# python / pandas - Storing binary list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Does anyone know what the most efficient way to store a binary list/array in Pandas would be?

I have a huge set (5 million+) of 256-bit binary hash codes that I'd like to create & store, each of which is created as a boolean numpy array.

Right now, I'm converting the binary code into a string like '0101010100...' and storing the hashes in one column of a pandas df; however when reading the file the operation to convert back from this string to a boolean array is quite time-consuming, and so I was hoping to optimise this by figuring out a better way to store the item in the dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save each digit in to a separate column of the dataframe, that way you won't need to do anything to convert the format, the underlying numpy array will already be the boolean array that you want:

```
hash1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
hash2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]

df = pd.DataFrame([hash1, hash2], dtype=bool)

df.iloc[0].values
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was also an option that I was considering! As I'm not quite sure how csvs store data, do you happen to know if this would take more or less storage space than storing as a one-column string?

Comment: uncompressed it will be bigger but if you compress the output (i.e. with `compression='gzip'`) it should be the same. another option would be to save the numpy array with `pickle`

Comment: Thank you, your advice has been really helpful. When I was looking up the stuff you mentioned I bumped across h5py, which seems like it might also be a good option?

Comment: yes depending on the number of csv files this might actually a better option now i think of it, you can save your numpy arrays directly into the hdf5 and accessing individual arrays will be faster than reading in csv from the file system

Comment: but if you just have a single array there's no real advantage to hdf5 i think, you may as well just use a csv or pickle